# Flutter KaTex library, Render Variables

Tags: flutter

im trying to display a variable via Katex. Tried to put it in with:

```
int testInt = 0;
KaTeX(                                                                      
  laTeXCode: Text(r' ${\frac{$testInt}{10}}'),                                                ),
```

and

```
int testInt = 0;
KaTeX(                                                                      
  laTeXCode: Text(r' ${\frac{'+ testInt.toString() +'}{10}}'),                                                ),
```

but both didn't work looked through the whole documentation but couldn't find anything.

Couldn't find an answer have decided to go for the CaTeX package until I find a solution (in the CaTeX package the 2nd way works (''+ variable  + ''))

Just saw the post again
Fixed it meanwhile I just copied the r and didn't knew the meaning
the r is for raw text which is handy for katex but it means it doesn't count variables etc. So if you remove the r it should work

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I don't get one it just displays the whole String as it stands in the code 
If i put in a number it displays a fraction